# How do I limit API requests in my app Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular

This is my first time trying to do that, if someone can guide that would be very helpful. What I need or I'm trying is to wait every HTTP answer when you do a request to the API until you don't get the answer you cant click in a button again, but really don't know how to start

***This is the code where I call to the function that does the POST method to the API***

```js
constructor(
    private _builder:FormBuilder, private usersService: UsersService,private router: Router,
    public _snackBar: MatSnackBar
    ) {}

  sendUser(){
    this.bSignIn = true;
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Identifier', this.loginForm.get('Identifier').value);
    formData.append('Password', this.loginForm.get('Password').value);
    setTimeout(() => {
    this.usersService.validateUserCredentials(formData)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.bSignIn = false;
        let auxRes: any = res;
        if(auxRes.type == 'success'){
          let auxUser = { 
            userId: auxRes.id,
            personId: auxRes.person_id,
            clientId: auxRes.client_id,
            projectId: auxRes.project_id
          }
          this.isSigned = true;
          //this.usersService.validateSigned(auxRes);
          localStorage.setItem('leadLogged', JSON.stringify(auxUser));
          this.goToUsersDashboard(auxRes.id);
        }
        else{
          this.openSnackBar(this.snackMessage);
          this.loginForm.reset();
        }
      },
      err => {
        console.log("else");
        window.alert('Introduce valid data');
        }
    )}, 4000);

  }
```

***ValidateUserCridentials is the function that does the POST method***

ValidateUsersCridentials function

```js
validateUserCredentials(user: any){                              
    return this.http.post(this.API_URL+'NONE-NONE-2/'+ENDPOINT_NAME+'/login/', user, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

***This is my button***

```html
<button mat-raised-button [class.black]="!loginForm.invalid" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

Comment: So you want to disable the button until the request finishes?

Comment: Yes I want that @mwilson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on logIn button, disable it in typescript code and then call the api.
Once you get the result, enable it again.

Do something like...

```
<button [disabled]="disabled" (click)="send()">Login</button>
```

Code behind:

```
async send(){
    // disable the login button
    this.disabled = true;

    // using delay for http response
    await this.delay(3000);

    this.disabled = false;

  }

  private delay(ms: number){
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
```

`disable` is property in your component and set it to `true` once you click on it and then make API request.

Quick demo --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qe11v1

Comment: You need to be more specific about the answer i understand your idea but really don't understand how to implemented

Comment: @Rinzler21 edited my answer with an angular playground link for understanding.

Comment: Yes this is pretty much what I'm looking for

Comment: did you bind the button disabled property to the typescript property in html?

Comment: Ready men i put this because of the properties of my button [disabled]="loginForm.invalid || disabled"

Answer (score 1):

Its easy, just use some variable `blockButton=false` - and when user click on button then inside click event handler, at the beginning use

```
if(this.blockButton) return;
this.blockButton=true;
```

so in this way you "block" click handler (at "first click") to execute main code as long as `blockButton` is `true`. Then in your `.subscribe` section (which is executed when your API return response) write

```
this.blockButton=false
```

This will unblock your button (only when you get response from serwer)

Comment: The problem i had with this is when someone click my submit button they can click it very fast and do many API requests i want it to be like you click one time wait the response and then click again, maybe your solution could work but how i tried with your example dont

Comment: @Rinzler21  when you use above solution - when someone click, and send request then when he click again (before response came) he will not send new request (because blockButton=true). This is how it works, but may be I don't understand your problem

Comment: Can you put an example?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a variable to track the disabled state, then apply the state to true when they click and return it to false when your subscription completes. The following example is created from the Angular example docs:

Relevant code:

**component.ts**

```
  disableConfig = false;

  showConfig() {
    this.configService.getConfig()
      .subscribe(
        (data: Config) => this.config = { ...data }, // success path
        error => this.error = error, // error path
        _ => this.disableConfig = false // on complete
      );
  }
```

**component.html**

```
  <button [disabled]="disableConfig" (click)="clear(); disableConfig = true; showConfig()">get</button>
```

Test on the following stackblitz by clicking the **get** button to see how it disables on click and re-enabled when a response is returned (or error). The code is contained within the **config** folder.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ycvjsz

Comment: This looks very good for me, let me see how can i implement something like this in my code